# how to fit dragged element in to dropped div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to to is fit the dragged element to parent after it's dragged succesfully (dragabble div is the same width and height like droppable element )

Can somebody help me how to "fit" those two  elements?

My code for droppable looks like that :

```
$(function() {
     $( ".cells" ).droppable({
          accept: "#image",
          activeClass: "hovered",
          hoverClass: "active",
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
             }
           });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first solution would be using `fit`

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ tolerance: "fit" }); //Draggable overlaps the droppable entirely.
```

a second one will be to modify top and left properties of the draggable element so itmatches the parent via `.css`

```
$(function() {
     $( ".cells" ).droppable({
          accept: "#image",
          activeClass: "hovered",
          hoverClass: "active",
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
          draggable.css("top",droppable.css("top"))
          draggable.css("left",droppable.css("left"))
             }
           });
});
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/sqY89/1/)

Comment: thanks ,a lot thats useful for sure but what in case when my divs don't have top and left properties ? I'm floating them . The only way of preforming is couning position of such div in document ?

Comment: give me a fiddle of what you are trying to achieve and i should try to help !

Comment: glance here : http://jsfiddle.net/h6r8N/2/ what I have in my code is the same "table" from divs, for everyone of them I try to drag image, then I'm trying to fit the image to that div, this is part of board game ;) thanks for help !

Comment: I've made what I want but have another issue now... When I'm putting my image into another div ( both has the same size) Scrollbar appear in my board :/ Do you know where can be the reason ?